# Argh! Last minute Browser/CSS Quirk in Firefox - can anyone help?

Tags: html, css, firefox, cross-browser, quirks-mode

So I started tweaking the html/css of this page. Nothing fancy as far as I can see.

Now it looks *completely* wrong in Firefox ([see for yourself](http://oscarspad.webdoma.in/)) and fine in every other browser I can think of. The html has been validated by the W3 tool. I am mystified, has anyone ever come across this before?

Comment: You need to clear floats on your menu.

Comment: UPDATE:
Thank you all for your prompt and entirely correct replies. I wouldn't have got that in a million years ;-). I've marked you all +1 and accepted the answer submitted by the person with the lowest rep. 
CSS is a fickle mistress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to clear the floats. Try adding this to your stylesheet:

```
table.layouttbl
{
    clear: both;
}
```

[This might help too](http://shingokko.com/blog-entry/positioning-elements-with-float-and-clear.html).

Comment: Though this works, there is no reason to have the menu floating, this is adding a hack to counter a previous hack.

Answer (score 1):

Try clearing the float you put on your menu.

```
<table cellspacing="0 " cellpadding="0" class="layouttbl" style="clear: left;">
```

You can put it in an actual style rule, or add another element and attach the clear to that instead.

Answer (score 1):

- Add `overflow: hidden` to `.page` class in `Site.css (line 108)`
- Add a new property: `.layouttbl {float: left}`

This fixes your issues in firefox. Make sure to check the site in other browsers as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your menu div has no need to float, remove float from that `#divMenu`. Be careful since you're defining `#divMenu` in 2 different places